# Get all properties of current class and base class

Tags: c#, propertydescriptor

I have 2 classes (lets say "BaseItem" and "ChildItem") with several **internal properties**. In the BaseClass i have defined a method which should read out all of this properties with

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
```

or

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType());
```

When i call this method in an instance of "ChildItem", i get only the properties that are defined in "ChildItem". What can i do to get also the the properties of "BaseItem"?

Regards

Dave

Comment: Why are you using `TypeDescriptor` and not `Type` directly to get the props?

Comment: You can have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245055/how-do-you-get-the-all-properties-of-a-class-and-its-base-classes-up-the-hierar

Comment: I tried this with Type.GetProperties also. The result is the same. Just properties defined in "ChildItem" will be returned.

Comment: Are the properties you want from base public or private/protected/internal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For internal properties (as clarified in the question comments), although not indicated (they're internal for a reason), you can use:

```
var internalProperties = GetType().GetProperties(
                            BindingFlags.Instance | 
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            BindingFlags.Public));
```

It's the flag `BindingFlags.NonPublic` that needs to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could just cast it to `BaseItem` and do `GetProperties()` separately..

Comment: That is my current workaround. I iterate through all base classes till i reach a specified one ("BaseItem). But i am really sure, there is a much faster solution available ;-)