# Loop through all the properties of an entity object and get the corresponding value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I'm using Entity framework 6 DBContext , Database First.

Let's say that I have an object , **myobj1** from one of entity.

Is there any way to loop through all the properties of this object and to get current value of each of them ?

Of course I need a general code that should work for any object from any entity.

Comment: i think reflection can help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the all properties of a class and its base classes (up the hierarchy) with Reflection? (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245055/how-do-you-get-the-all-properties-of-a-class-and-its-base-classes-up-the-hierar)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
var values = instance.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(instance, null));
```

If you also want the name of the property use this:

```
var values = instance.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => 
        new 
        {
            property = x.Name, 
            value = x.GetValue(instance, null)
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.property, y => y.value);
```

This selects all the properties of the given type and gets its name and value for the desired instance.

However this approach only works for simple, non-indexed properties.

EDIT: Also have a look on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on Bindingflags to restrict the properties returned from `GetType().GetProperties` - in particular when you need the properties of your base-class also.

Comment: Sorry , but what about non-scalar properties , that maybe should be excluded ?

Comment: yes , properties that have no primitive types.For example a property like that : Public Overridable Property Chlds As ICollection(Of Chld) = New HashSet(Of Chld)

Comment: Maybe `GetProperties.Where(x => x.IsValueType).Select(...)` will do that selecting only value-types?

Comment: the IsValueType is unknown.

Comment: Ooops, yeap true, I ment `x => x.PropertyType.IsValueType`.